# Create ul and li elements in javascript.

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create ul and li element in my codes by using javascript. I have following:

```
var test=document.createElement('section');
test.setAttribute('id','test');

var ul=document.createElement('ul');


document.body.appendChild(test);
test.appendChild(ul);

for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){

    var li=document.createElement('li');

    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML=li.innerHTML + array[i];

}
```

My array is parsed using json_encode from php

```
array[0]='aaa';
array[1]='bbb';
array[2]='ccc';
```

CSS

```
section { 

    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 3px solid red;

}
```

Everything works fine except the list style dot is outside of my section tag.

It displays like this in Chrome and IE but firefox work fine.

```
 -------------
*| aaa       |
*| bbb       |
*| ccc       |
 -------------
```

I want my dot inside my section tag. Anyone idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: tried using `list-style-position: inside`?

Comment: lol it works. simple as that. guess Chrome and IE need it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It works for me without - http://jsfiddle.net/XepXZ/1

Comment: @Alnitak, that's correct. just unchecked the `normalize CSS` on jsFiddle and realized **that** did the trick (by removing all reset styles).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `CSS` property `list-style-position` to position the bullet:

```
list-style-position:inside /* or outside */;
```

Answer (score 41):

Here is my working code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
   ul#proList{list-style-position: inside}
   li.item{list-style:none; padding:5px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="renderList"></div>
</body>
<script>
    (function(){
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        ul.setAttribute('id','proList');

        productList = ['Electronics Watch','House wear Items','Kids wear','Women Fashion'];

        document.getElementById('renderList').appendChild(ul);
        productList.forEach(renderProductList);

        function renderProductList(element, index, arr) {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.setAttribute('class','item');

            ul.appendChild(li);

            li.innerHTML=li.innerHTML + element;
        }
    })();
</script>
</html>
```

working jsfiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sunnysm/so7qfg9p/)

Answer (score 6):

Try out below code snippet:

```
 var list = [];
 var text;

function update() {
    console.log(list);    

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
       console.log( i );
       var letters;
       var ul = document.getElementById("list");
       var li = document.createElement("li");

       li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(list[i]));
       ul.appendChild(li);

       letters += "<li>"  + list[i] + "</li>";
    }

 document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = letters;

}

function myFunction() {
    text = prompt("enter TODO");  
    list.push(text);
    update();
}
```

Comment: you seem to do several times the same thing, by doing it first with dom and finally replacing everything with html

Comment: it would be easier if you call onload function init(){
    var div = document.getElementById("divList");
    var ul  = document.createElement('ul');
    ul.setAttribute('id',"ul1");
    div.appendChild(ul);
} and then call the following function from a button: function entry() {
    var text = prompt("enter TODO");  
    var ul = document.getElementById("ul1");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent=text;
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

Answer (score 2):

Great then. Let's create a simple function that takes an array and prints our an ordered listview/list inside a div tag.

Step 1: Let's say you have an div with "contentSectionID" id.`<div id="contentSectionID"></div>`

Step 2: We then create our javascript function that returns a list component and takes in an array:

```
function createList(spacecrafts){

var listView=document.createElement('ol');

for(var i=0;i<spacecrafts.length;i++)
{
    var listViewItem=document.createElement('li');
    listViewItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(spacecrafts[i]));
    listView.appendChild(listViewItem);
}

return listView;
}
```

Step 3: Finally we select our div and create a listview in it:

```
document.getElementById("contentSectionID").appendChild(createList(myArr));
```