# Turn js objects into html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

OK, so I have some JS that pulls data from JSON via URL.
I know Want to turn each object (author_name, rating, author_url) into js ID's so i can call the ID in html.

for example

```
<ul>
    <li id=''></li>
    <li id=''></li>
    <li id=''></li>
</ul>
```

this is my JS code so far

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=123-mg&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.getDetails({
            placeId: '123'
        }, function(place, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for(var i=0; i <= place.reviews.length; i++) {
                    console.log(place.reviews[i]);
                    alert(place.reviews[i].author_name);
                    alert(place.reviews[i].rating);
                    alert(place.reviews[i].author_url);
                    alert(place.reviews[i].text);
                    alert(place.reviews[i].relative_time_description);
                    alert(place.reviews[i].profile_photo_url);
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

what is the best way to get these into html so I can style and use around the page?

Comment: Create an `li` element with the desired content and `append()` it to your `ul`

Comment: Nice information, thanks ill try this. like ? (place.reviews[i].author_name) append(li) ?

Comment: eval , innerHtml , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351135/create-ul-and-li-elements-in-javascript

Comment: Take a look ad `lodash templates` or any [other template](http://ejs.co/) script, it's just what you need

Comment: Thanks ill look into this now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your html file will look like this:

```
<ul id="parent">

</ul>
```

Include the jquery script in the header of your html.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now this is the code you want:

```
var child = someVariable; //Where somevariable is the variable you fetch from the url.
$("#parent").append('<li id="id_you_want_to_give">'+child+'</li>');
```

You create a `li` tag for each of the variable you want to append and append it to parent.

Comment: some var could be (place.reviews[i].relative_time_description); ?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically create DOM element and append to existing HTML

```
var parent = $('ul');
parent.html('');

$.each(place.reviews, function () {
    parent
       .append('<li class="parent-name">'+this.author_name+'</li>')
       .append('<li class="rating">'+this.rating+'</li>')
       /* ... */
    ;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a loop that creates `li` elements (with whatever content pattern you need) and appends them to the `ul` element. This is vanilla JS:

```js
var reviews = [
  {
    author_name: "John Smith",
    rating: 5,
    author_url: "http://johnsmith.com",
    text: "This place is fantastic!",
    relative_time_description: "",
    profile_photo_url: ""
  },
  {
    author_name: "Jim Conway",
    rating: 3,
    author_url: "http://jimconway.com",
    text: "The food was ok, but the coding is mediocre.",
    relative_time_description: "",
    profile_photo_url: ""
  }
];

function updateReviews(data){
  var reviews = document.getElementById('reviews')
   for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
     var li = document.createElement('li');
     li.id = "review"+i;
     li.innerText = data[i].author_name +": "+data[i].text;
     reviews.append(li);
   }
}

updateReviews(reviews);
```

```html
<ul id="reviews">
  
</ul>
```